# Reactjs redux: Fetch PUT method sending only an OPTIONS method, even when the status is 200

Tags: reactjs, fetch, redux

I am sending a PUT method as follow (checking with chrome):

```
function checkStatus(response) {
  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
    console.log("status: ", response.statusText);
    return response
  } else {
    var error = new Error(response.statusText)
    error.response = response
    throw error
  }
}

import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch'
return dispatch => {
        dispatch(requestPosts(data));
        return fetch('/trendings', {
            method: 'PUT',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Authorization: Config.token
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
        })
        .then(checkStatus)
        .then(reponse => {
            console.log('request succeeded with JSON response', data);
            dispatch(successSent("The output list has been successfully sent!"));
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log('request failed', err);
            dispatch(failSent("Error on sending request: " + err));
        });
```

and the problem is that it's returning an OPTIONS method with status 200 only.

The problem is that it should follow with the PUT method. Furthermore, it should return an error as the API endpoint isn't ready yet.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Care to show us the API?

Answer (score 4):

You need to add `credentials: 'same-origin'` and to remove the `'Content-Type' : 'application.json'` from headers list since [isomorphic-fetch doesn't seem to handle it well](https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch/issues/51) to avoid this issue otherwise the first `isormophic-fetch` will only triggers the `OPTION` request to fetch information about the server (it's the default browser behavior for cross origin requests) :

```
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch'
return dispatch => {
        dispatch(requestPosts(data));
        return fetch('/trendings', {
            method: 'PUT',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': Config.token
            },
            credentials: 'same-origin', // you need to add this line
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
        })
        .then(checkStatus)
        .then(reponse => {
            console.log('request succeeded with JSON response', data);
            dispatch(successSent("The output list has been successfully sent!"));
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log('request failed', err);
            dispatch(failSent("Error on sending request: " + err));
        });
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I tried it but it seems that it's still get stuck on "OPTIONS" Method, with status 200. Weird!

Comment: Ok, maybe you could try to remove the `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`from headers list. `OPTION` is the natural request triggered by browser for crossorigin request but `isomorphic-fetch` seems to have some difficulties to handle the above header well. I've updated my answer.